# Xcode: does not work performSeguewithIdentifier

Tags: swift, xcode

Photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWz8B.png

I pass by pressing any button on the Game ViewController, there is a title on the button determines the level and load it:

```
let sceneView = GameScene(fileNamed: "Level " + String(buttonTitle))
let skView = SKView(frame: self.view.frame)
self.view.addSubview(skView)
skView.showsFPS = true
skView.showsNodeCount = true
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
sceneView!.scaleMode = .aspectFill
skView.presentScene(sceneView)
```

And then I can easily go to the main menu with the help of Segue:

```
if node.name == "menu"{
   self.viewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToMainMenu", sender: self)
   self.removeAllActions()
   self.removeAllChildren()
}
```

But if you go to any scene (any level) and to update the level using the retry button:

```
if node.name == "retry" {
   let currentScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "Level "+String(thisScene))
   let transition = SKTransition.doorsCloseHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
   currentScene!.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
   self.scene!.view?.presentScene(currentScene!, transition: transition)
}
```

then

```
if node.name == "menu"{
   self.viewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToMainMenu", sender: self)
   self.removeAllActions()
   self.removeAllChildren()
}
```

**Stop working**. Works only

```
   self.removeAllActions()
   self.removeAllChildren()
```

I do not understand what was going on.